# Real-time retrieval of an input in a Symfony form made with make:form

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I made a form that works perfectly with the Symfony make: form command.

What I would like to do is that when I write in the "barcode" field of my form, the "serial number" field fills in real time with the end of the data (about 10 characters from the end) that was put in the "barcode" field.

My form creation file with the FormBuilder => ProductType.php

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('supplier', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Supplier::class,
                'placeholder' => ' ',
                'choice_label' => 'compagny_name',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $entityRepository) {
                    return $entityRepository->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->orderBy('s.compagny_name', 'ASC');
                }
            ])
            ->add('product_category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => ProductCategory::class,
                'placeholder' => ' ',
                'choice_label' => 'type',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $entityRepository) {
                    return $entityRepository->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->orderBy('c.type', 'ASC');
                }
            ])
            ->add('reference', TextType::class)
            ->add('serial_number', TextType::class)
            ->add('barcode', TextType::class);
    }
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#product_barcode').on('input',function(e){
        $("#product_serial_number").text($(this).val());
    });

});
```

Template for adding a product => add.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
  <div class="form-fields">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
        {{ form_label(form.supplier, 'Supplier', {
        'label_attr': {'class': 'custom-form-label'}
          }) 
        }}
        {{ form_errors(form.supplier) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.supplier) }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
        {{ form_label(form.product_category, 'Category', {
        'label_attr': {'class': 'custom-form-label'}
          }) 
        }}
        {{ form_errors(form.product_category) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.product_category) }}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row my-5 justify-content-between">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
        {{ form_label(form.reference, 'Reference', {
        'label_attr': {'class': 'custom-form-label'}
          }) 
        }}
        {{ form_errors(form.reference) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.reference) }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
        {{ form_label(form.serial_number, 'Serial number', {
        'label_attr': {'class': 'custom-form-label'}
          }) 
        }}
        {{ form_errors(form.serial_number) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.serial_number) }}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        {{ form_label(form.barcode, 'Barcode', {
        'label_attr': {'class': 'custom-form-label'}
          })
        }}
        {{ form_errors(form.barcode) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.barcode) }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
  </div>
  {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Do you have any idea why my JQuery is not working?

Or is it possible to achieve the desired results in another way?

Thanks

Comment: Define "is not working". Are there errors in the console? Do you get unexpected results? Where do you set the `product_barcode` id to the input?

Comment: There are no errors in the console, in fact nothing happens when you enter the barcode field. 
The input id is automatically created by the Form Builder

    
<input type="text" id="product_barcode" name="product[barcode]" required="required" class="form-control">

<input type="text" id="product_serial_number" name="product[serial_numbe]" required="required" class="form-control">

Comment: I assumed that, but wanted to check. It's not a good idea to rely on Symfony generated ids, because if they change their internal implementation of how ids are generated, your code might break. But, for the time being, let's focus on the issue. If you add a `console.log` with any message inside your on input handler, does it show? You might also try to select both `$('#product_barcode')` and `$("#product_serial_number")` directly in the console and see if the correct elements are selected.

Comment: That output mentions `prosthesis_serial_number`, but in your code you reference `product_serial_number`.

Comment: Sorry I had tested it on another project... `w.fn.init [input#product_barcode.form-control] 0: input#prosthesis_barcode.form-control w.fn.init [input#product_serial_number.form-control] 0: input#product_serial_number.form-control`

Comment: I see no immediate reason why it wouldn't work. When you inspect your input, does it show an event attached to it?

Comment: no there is no event attached to it

Comment: Hm. Add `console.log('test')` into the `$(document).ready` function, before you attach the listener and see if it shows up.

Comment: The `console.log('test')` appears correctly

Comment: and if I put it in my listener function I get a new 'test' in my console every time I press a key

Comment: Gah... they're both inputs. Use `val()` instead of `text()`.

Comment: arrhhh... thanks my hero xD do you know if it is possible to retrieve in this way only the last 5 characters of the barcode to display only those in the serial_number ?

Comment: Of course, you just have to do the string manipulation before you assign it with `val`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just because you used  `$("#product_serial_number").text($(this).val());` ?!

If `product_serial_number` is an HTMLInputElement, your should use `$('#product_serial_number').val($(this).val());`

The JQuery `.text()` stands for retrieving or updating the text content of an element (eg: `element.textContent`)

Comment: The error came from the `.text()` and was solved by replacing it with `.val()`